# CursorLoader, get URI for local database

Tags: android, sqlite, uri, android-cursorloader

I'm a newbie android programmer and I recently followed a tutorial which shows how to create a local SQLite database and then access the database by using SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery to return a Cursor. I would like to modify my app to use CursorLoader which is apparently a better way to access the database.
My problem is the CursorLoader constructor expects a URI to be given. Do I just input "file:///[path to db]"? Seems a bit messy.

Comment: You should post the link to the tutorial for completeness

Answer (score 8):

The reason behind cursor loader accepting a URI is that it expects to query a contentProvider and not a raw database.

So I suggest that you create a content provider which internally uses your database, so that you can use the CursorLoader class directly.

The advantage of using a content provider is that it encapsulates better your data and you can easily leverage a lot of apis from android directly.

Here are some guides on how to create a content provider

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/

If you choose not to create a ContentProvider you can extend [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) or the cursor loader directly to query the data the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at CommonsWare's [LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex#readme) library. It allows you to use a `Loader` with a local `SQLiteDatabase`, so you don't have to go to all the bother of creating your own `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I'd like to at least get my own ContentProvider implementation working, because it seems to be the 'standard' way of doing things even if it does seem overblown for small standalone apps. But I'll have a look at this library at some point once I understand the basics.

Comment: From git: `THIS PROJECT IS DISCONTINUED. Use it at your own risk. If you are maintaining a public fork that you would like others to consider using, add an issue asking for a link to your fork from this README.`